# Shortcut for moving window between monitors in Mac OS

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors

I am using Snow Leopard and I am curious whether there are any shortcuts for moving windows between monitors similar to how Winows has:
<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to move the current window to the left or right display.

Comment: Some alternative options, all of which also cost around $14... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706987/mac-os-x-keyboard-shortcut-for-moving-active-window-to-another-screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no built in way to do this, but [Optimal Layout](http://most-advantageous.com/optimal-layout/) adds this kind of feature with full keyboard control over window position and size.

Disclaimer: I'm the developer of Optimal Layout